# on attachment.php, how to display previous and next attachment links that follow the same order as a custom WP Query

Tags: wp-query, templates, attachments, next-post-link, previous-post-link

## Current behavior

I have a media page that uses a custom WP_Query to return all thumbnails of media library attachments (regardless of post parent) with a custom taxonomy of `media_visibility` that has the term of `published`. This is working as expected on the media page. It's using my template file [page-media.php](https://github.com/mrengy/vanguard-history/blob/668d546d2f24f4e0859a7e1eb03a8ceffbe8ba2a/wp-content/themes/vanguard-history/page-media.php). Relevant code sample:

```
  // how many media thumbnails to show at first.
  $thumbnails_to_show = 42;

  //Protect against arbitrary paged values
  $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;

        // query media
        $media_query_args = array(
            'post_type'   => 'attachment',
            'post_status' => 'any',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'paged' => $paged,
            'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'media_visibility',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => 'published',
                    ),
            ),
            'posts_per_page' => $thumbnails_to_show,
        );
        $media_query = new WP_Query ($media_query_args);

        $thumbnails = array();

        if ( $media_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $media_query->have_posts() ) : $media_query->the_post();
                // store thumbnails in array
                $thumbnails[] = wp_get_attachment_link( get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail', true );
            endwhile;

        endif; // end of media loop
```

When one clicks on a link on a thumbnail image, it loads a page showing the attachment and previous / next links using [my attachment.php file](https://github.com/mrengy/vanguard-history/blob/668d546d2f24f4e0859a7e1eb03a8ceffbe8ba2a/wp-content/themes/vanguard-history/attachment.php). Relevant code sample:

```
    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

        previous_post_link();
        next_post_link();

        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
            comments_template();
        endif;

    endwhile; // End of the loop.
```

Here, there seems to be an issue with the order of posts / the different loops. On some (maybe all) attachment pages, `previous_post_link()` is displaying a link to the same attachment shown rather than the previous one, and `next_post_link()` is not displaying anything.

[image: current behavior of attachment page]

I also have another sort of page (a custom post type called "year story") that has a slightly different WP_Query to display multiple thumbnails - it's restricting the attachments to those that have the same terms in a couple of taxonomies. Full code in [single-year_story.php](https://github.com/mrengy/vanguard-history/blob/73f2aaa695ff80eb76935e60a829c53fb7809318/wp-content/themes/vanguard-history/single-year_story.php):

```
        //get taxonomies from the post
        $this_ensemble = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(),'ensemble')[0]->slug;
        $this_year = wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(),'vhs_year')[0]->slug;

        // how many media thumbnails to show at first
        $thumbnails_to_show = 6;

        // query media
        $media_query_args = array(
            'post_type'   => 'attachment',
            'post_status' => 'any',

            'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'ensemble',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $this_ensemble,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'vhs_year',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => $this_year,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'media_visibility',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => 'published',
                    ),
            ),

            'posts_per_page' => $thumbnails_to_show,
        );
        $media_query = new WP_Query ($media_query_args);

        $thumbnails = array();

        if ( $media_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $media_query->have_posts() ) : $media_query->the_post();
                // store thumbnails in array
                $thumbnails[] = wp_get_attachment_link( get_the_ID(), 'thumbnail', true );

            endwhile;

        endif; // end of media loop
```

Note that in both of these cases, the attachments don't necessarily have post parents. I set up the site to be fairly dynamic with visitors able to upload their own attachments, and I don't want to assign post parents to them when this happens (because we might not have created the corresponding year story post yet).

## Desired behavior

What I want on the attachment page is to **have previous and next text links that page through the attachment pages in the same order they appear on the WP_Query on the referring page (like a year story or media page) and only including those attachments shown on the referring page's WP_Query**. If someone comes directly to an attachment page, I want these previous and next links to behave the same way as if someone came from the **media page**. If someone comes to the attachment page from an attachment in the body of a post or page, I want to either:

1. have the previous and next links cycle through the attachments with the same post parent, or
2. hide the previous and next links - they're not very important for this case.

## Other attempts

I tried some other approaches like `the_post_navigation()` and `get_previous_image_link() / get_next_image_link()` but did not get what I was trying to achieve here. I also tried [replacing `the loop` on attachment.php with the same custom WP_Query](https://github.com/mrengy/vanguard-history/blob/48da07f774318fbe1d0efad46709d1e31d8bc91b/wp-content/themes/vanguard-history/attachment.php) that I used on page-media.php but this ended up always displaying the first attachment returned in the query, rather than the attachment specified in the URL.

## Links

[View the media page on staging site](https://historyscv-stage.dreamhosters.com/media/)

[View a year story page on staging site](https://historyscv-stage.dreamhosters.com/year_story/2001-scv/)

(In order to view the above links, log in as
username: `stackexchange`
password: `guest`)

[Theme code](https://github.com/mrengy/vanguard-history/tree/668d546d2f24f4e0859a7e1eb03a8ceffbe8ba2a/wp-content/themes/vanguard-history)

This customized theme is based on [underscores](https://underscores.me/).

Comment: One stub of an idea - perhaps I need to capture the current post on attachment.php as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28345562/370407) (but without the post_parent reference) and make previous / next links relative to that?